# My cat is 13 years old and likes to sit and doze off sitting in the litter

Tags: cats, senior-pet, sight

My 13 year old cat has trouble walking sometimes, and she is going blind. Her eyes are always watering, and she's not running around or anything because of her age. She just started to sit and doze off in the litter even if she's not going to the bathroom. Is she going to be ok or should I take her to the vet?

Answer (score 4):

Cats can live much longer than 13, so I wouldn't put any particular behavior on the idea that she is old.

Yes, take your cat to the vet. Strange behavior is a pets way of letting you know something is wrong.

When my cat exhibited similar litter box sleeping, it turned out she had a UTI. A little medicine and she was back in bed and out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

You should always take your cat to the vet whenever there is a significant behavior change.

We cannot diagnose your cat's health problem over the internet, only a veterinarian can do that with a physical exam. She may be okay, or she may have a significant health problem. Your vet should be able to determine the problem.